# Can't install ImageMagick on CentOS 7 [magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-distribute-cache.lo]

Tags: centos, imagemagick

I am having some issues installing ImageMagick on my CentOS 7 server.

Here is the commands I used:

```
./configure --without-threads
```

Everything looks ok.

```
                  Option                        Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shared libraries  --enable-shared=yesyes
Static libraries  --enable-static=yesyes
Module support    --with-modules=nono
GNU ld            --with-gnu-ld=yesyes
Quantum depth     --with-quantum-depth=1616
High Dynamic Range Imagery
                  --enable-hdri=nono

Install documentation:yes

Delegate Library Configuration:
BZLIB             --with-bzlib=yesyes
Autotrace         --with-autotrace=nono
DJVU              --with-djvu=yesyes
DPS               --with-dps=yesno
FFTW              --with-fftw=yesno
FlashPIX          --with-fpx=yesno
FontConfig        --with-fontconfig=yesyes
FreeType          --with-freetype=yesyes
Ghostscript lib   --with-gslib=nono
Graphviz          --with-gvc=no
JBIG              --with-jbig=yesno
JPEG v1           --with-jpeg=yesyes
JPEG-2000         --with-jp2=
LCMS v1           --with-lcms=yesno
LCMS v2           --with-lcms2=yesno
LQR               --with-lqr=yesno
LTDL              --with-ltdl=yesno
LZMA              --with-lzma=yesyes
Magick++          --with-magick-plus-plus=yesno (failed tests)
OpenEXR           --with-openexr=yesyes
OpenJP2           --with-openjp2=yesno
PANGO             --with-pango=yesyes
PERL              --with-perl=nono
PNG               --with-png=yesyes
RSVG              --with-rsvg=nono
TIFF              --with-tiff=yesyes
WEBP              --with-webp=yesno
WMF               --with-wmf=nono
X11               --with-x=yes
XML               --with-xml=yesyes
ZLIB              --with-zlib=yesyes

Delegate Program Configuration:
GhostPCL          Nonepcl6 (unknown)
GhostXPS          Nonegxps (unknown)
Ghostscript       Nonegs (9.07)

Font Configuration:
Apple fonts       --with-apple-font-dir=defaultnone
Dejavu fonts      --with-dejavu-font-dir=defaultnone
Ghostscript fonts --with-gs-font-dir=default/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/
Windows fonts     --with-windows-font-dir=defaultnone

X11 Configuration:
      X_CFLAGS        = 
      X_PRE_LIBS      = -lSM -lICE
      X_LIBS          = 
      X_EXTRA_LIBS    = 

Options used to compile and link:
  PREFIX          = /usr/local
  EXEC-PREFIX     = /usr/local
  VERSION         = 6.9.0
  CC              = gcc -std=gnu99 -std=gnu99
  CFLAGS          = -pthread -I/usr/include/OpenEXR -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/freetype2 -g -O2 -Wall -march=corei7-avx -fexceptions -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
  CPPFLAGS        = -pthread -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng15 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/freetype2 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/libxml2
  PCFLAGS         = 
  DEFS            = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
  LDFLAGS         = 
  LIBS            = 
  CXX             = g++
  CXXFLAGS        = 
  FEATURES        = DPC
  DELEGATES       = bzlib djvu mpeg fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lzma openexr pango png ps tiff x xml zlib
```

Then I do:

```
make -j16
```

And I get this:

```
magick/distribute-cache.c:751:28: warning: 'DistributePixelCacheClient' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static HANDLER_RETURN_TYPE DistributePixelCacheClient(void *socket)
                            ^
make[1]: *** [magick/magick_libMagickCore_6_Q16_la-distribute-cache.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from magick/magick.c:72:0:
./magick/semaphore-private.h:36:3: warning: 'semaphore_mutex' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   semaphore_mutex = 0;
   ^
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/ImageMagick-6.9.0-2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Those appear to be warnings and not errors. What is above that? Also is there a reason you aren't using the CentOS7 `ImageMagick` package?

Comment: It's older. I check and it as not been updated since 2012.

Comment: Yes, it is an older version. That's sort-of how RHEL/CentOS works. Do you need something from the newer version? Also realize that RHEL/CentOS backport security/etc. patches to their older versions so it isn't exactly as old as it appears to be at first glance.